# Android UI Update Thread - saving and restoring it

Tags: android, save, state, restore

How do I properly do that?

I have a stopwatch and I'm saving it's state in `onSaveInstance` and restoring it's state in `onRestoreInstance`...

Now I've following problem: if I stop the thread in `onSaveInstance` and the screen get's locked or turned off, `onRestoreInstance` is not called and the stopwatch is not continuing...
If I don't stop it, the stopwatch is running in background on and on even when the screen is off or the activity is not active anymore...

So what's the usual way to handle such a thing?

PS:
I even have a working solution, a local variable to save the running state in the `onStop` event and restarting the thread in the `onStart` event... But I still want to know if there's a "default" solution using the android system itself....

Comment: Do you want the stopwatch to continue when the user is no longer seeing the activity?  I.E., if the user gets a phone call, should the stopwatch stop or keep going?

Comment: the stopwatch should STOP, when the activity is not visible... it's just a waste of resources if it keeps running...

Comment: Not if you wanted to make a notification if it runs out or show it counting down via notification.

Comment: I want that too, but therefore I'm using the android AlarmManager... so the stopwatch (just a visual feedback) can be stopped, if the activity is not visible... and a thread would not be safe enough for the alarm... it could be killed... a service would be an alternative, but I read, that the AlarmManager is better, considering the resources...

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  I better now understand what you're doing.  I thought you were using the thread to count.  Right now it sounds like you're using it to update the UI.

Instead, what you probably should be doing is using a self-calling `Handler`.  `Handler`s are nifty little classes that can run asynchronously.  They're used all over the place in Android because of their diversity.

```
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000; // in milliseconds. Will update every 1 second

Handler clockHander = new Handler();

Runnable UpdateClock extends Runnable {
   View clock;

   public UpdateClock(View clock) {
      // Do what you need to update the clock
      clock.invalidate(); // tell the clock to redraw.
      clockHandler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_INTERVAL); // call the handler again
   }
}

UpdateClock runnableInstance;

public void start() {
   // start the countdown
   clockHandler.post(this); // tell the handler to update
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   // create your UI including the clock view
   View myClockView = getClockView(); // custom method. Just need to get the view and pass it to the runnable.
   runnableInstance = new UpdateClock(myClockView);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
   clockHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // removes all messages from the handler. I.E. stops it
}
```

What this will do is post messages to the `Handler` which will run.  It posts every 1 second in this case.  There is a *slight* delay because `Handlers` are message queues that run when available.  They also run on the thread that they're created on, so if you create it on the UI thread you will be able to update the UI without any fancy tricks.  You remove the messages in the `onPause()` to stop updating the UI.  The clock can continue to run in the background, but you won't be showing it to the user anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I just got into Android programming, but I don't think `onRestoreInstance` will be called in that situation because you're not switching from one activity to another.  I think your best bet is to call `onPause` which will then call `onSaveInstance` if you need it to, but use `onResume` which might or might not call `onRestoreInstance`.

Comment: `onPause` and `onResume` would be an alternative to my way (using `onStop` and `onStart`), but I don't get a Bundle in the `onResume` event either... the `onSaveInstance` event is called anyway, but the `onRestoreInstance` is never called afterwards...